# If two mysql queries can not be executed in one prepared statement, should I be worried about SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-injection

Here is small pseudo-sample:

```
        SET @StA = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE hackTable 
        (id INT(10) 
        name VARCHAR(45)); SELECT * FROM hackTable;');            
        PREPARE statementA FROM @StA;
        EXECUTE statementA;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE statementA;
```

This prepared statement throws error 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax..).

Here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html
it is said that:

> ...a user variable that contains the text of the SQL statement. The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

If table name is set dynamically from user input(yes, I have read many articles about techniques like escaping, whitelisting, etc. how to prevent SQL injection attacks.), there are risks of SQL injection, but since putting some another query at the end of the first will throw error, this limits the risk to only creating corrupt table? Have I understood this correctly or there are other ways how to mess up my query more seriously?

Comment: a parse error is a error which stop execution direclty so it's never injectable.. To proof the table will not be created see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW5u69Q8j7TkE4AqBdmi9K/0)

Comment: a better way is to create stored procedure and pass user input as a parameter. this will allow you to sleep better and you can also handle table creation better (i.e. check if table already exists)

Comment: *"a better way is to create stored procedure and pass user input as a parameter."* @Vasya a stored procedure can still be prone to SQL injections.

Comment: Fun fact: you can't use user input for table names when using **prepared statements**, if you pass the table name as parameter. You'll always get an error. Try it.

Comment: The only way `PREPARE/EXECUTE` protects against SQL injections is to use/implement `EXECUTE <statement> USING @<variable>`..

Comment: *"Fun fact: you can't use user input for table names when using prepared statements"* @Mjh Fun fact that's why you need to "cheat" the system see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW5u69Q8j7TkE4AqBdmi9K/3)

Comment: @RaymondNijland - that's a great attempt at a cheat, but I believe you're aware of being unable to use various special characters that aren't allowed for table names and which would basically be allowed to pass your statement :) nevertheless, nice one!

Comment: *"but I believe you're aware of being unable to use various special characters that aren't allowed for table names and which would basically be allowed to pass your statement"* Yes iám @Mjh this wasn't a full "cheat" you would have to do more "filtering" with `REPLACE()` for example but now i think about it the table can not  be created with invalid special characters it will error. *"nevertheless, nice one!"* Thanks

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for the effort! I have tested samples that you have provided and one question arrised - if I SET @tableName='hacktable (idHacked INT(10) , nameHacked VARCHAR(45)) --' I can still insert corrupted table so I don't quite understand the point of doing this. I am quite new to this stuff so maybe I am not seeing something?

Comment: yea the "cheat" isn't (really fully) production ready as it is (jet).. it still needs heavy filtering and testing also.. like `SET @tableName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tableName, ' ', 1);` for example.. see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW5u69Q8j7TkE4AqBdmi9K/3) .. **i doubt you would want to use this on production as this "cheat" is a heavy workaround and meant for learning purpose**

Comment: @RaymondNijland I see. Btw, I think you posted the same demo. Would you have any recommendations how to improve security when creating tables dynamically that could be used in production environment?

Comment: *"Would you have any recommendations how to improve security when creating tables dynamically that could be used in production environment? "* Yes the only safe way would be to make a  SQL parser and make a syntax tree out of it and compare that with a syntax tree which is allowed.

Comment: Heavy simplified for example  `SELECT * FROM table` will become a array/vector `[SELECT, *, FROM, table]` and this is allowed by the whitelist `[SELECT, *, FROM, table_identifier]` but `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id =  1` is not allowed because it's `[SELECT, *, FROM, table, WHERE, id, =, 1]` which does not match the whitelist there is no valid way to trick or inject into this "algorithm" unless the (string) functions in your programming laugauge are prone for NULL bytes injections then you would need to be carefull.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've tried to google what you have described, but nothing reasonable comes up. Do you happen to have any reference to further reading and/or tutorials on this matter?

Comment: *"I've tried to google what you have described,"* Google with [abstract parse tree sql injection](https://www.google.com/?q=abstract+parse+tree+sql+injection) then you should find some articles, especially the PDF in the Google result with the title *"A Parse Tree Model for Analyzing And Detecting SQL Injection"* is a great article i can't directly link to that.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for you help! To wrap it up, I think that your first comment answers the question I asked, so if you could post it as an answer, I would accept it.